# Ruby aws-sdk - ".exists?" says the file doesn't exist even though I see it in the bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I stuck all afternoon on checking whether an uploaded file to AWS S3 exists or not. I use Ruby On Rails and the gem called `aws-sdk`, `v2`.

First of all - the file exists in the bucket, it is located here:

```
test_bucket/users/10/file_test.pdf
```

There's no typo, this is the exact path. Also, the bucket + credentials are set up correctly.

And here's how I try to check the existence of the file:

```
config = {region: 'us-west-1', bucket: AWS_S3_CONFIG['bucket'], key: AWS_S3_CONFIG['access_key_id'], secret: AWS_S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key']}
Aws.config.update({region: config[:region], 
                   credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(config[:key], config[:secret]),
                   :s3 => { :region => 'us-east-1' }})
bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(config[:bucket])

puts bucket.object("file_test.pdf").exists?
```

The output is always `false`.

I also tried `puts bucket.object("test_bucket/users/10/file_test.pdf").exists?`, but still `false`.

Also, I tried to make the file public in the AWS S3 dashboard, but no success, still `false`. The file is visible when click on the generated link.

But the problem is that when I check with using `aws-sdk` if the file exist, the output is still `false`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the full path to the object (not including the bucket name) - `users/10/file_test.pdf`